# How do I use RegisterClientScriptBlock to register JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

ASP.NET 2.0 provides the `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` method for registering JavaScript in an ASP.NET Page.

The issue I'm having is passing the script when it's located in another directory.  Specifically, the following syntax does not work:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "scriptName", "../dir/subdir/scriptName.js", true);
```

Instead of dropping the code into the page like [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479390.aspx#javawasp2_topic7) says it should, it instead displays `../dir/subdir/script.js` , my question is this:

Has anyone dealt with this before, and found a way to drop in the javascript in a separate file?  Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're after is:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.GetType(), "scriptName", "../dir/subdir/scriptName.js")
```

Answer (score 2):

use: ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(key, url);

Answer (score -1):

Your script value has to be a full script, so put in the following for your script value.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='yourpathhere'></script>
```

Comment: Could you please extend the answer?